# For Subqueriers - What is good? HQL or Criteria -DetachedCriteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

Consider the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE T1.id = (SELECT id1 FROM T2 where T2.id1 = (SELECT id2 FROM T3))
 AND T1.anotherId IN (SELECT id3 FROM T3);
```

I would guess HQL is more efficient than using Criteria API with DetachedCriteria?

I have implemented (mostly) Criteria in my project, it just looks so OOP. Also easier on eyes (this depends on perception)

Thoughts?

Comment: This isn't a constructive question.

Comment: This query could be reimplemented without any single subquery using joins. HQL and criteria shouldn't make any difference: most of the time is spent executing the query and fetching results, whatever you use to build the query. If you and your colleagues find criteria more readable than HQL (which I disagree with), then use criteria.

Comment: efficient in what? a) charcters to write, b) execution time, c) parsing time? HQL wins clearly in a) but b) and c) should be almost equal

Comment: Character to write, yes. But i would have thought it wins in parsing time too. May be i am wrong. JB , yes, I wrote it using the join. 

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

For complicated queries I prefer using Criteria API.

When you write JPQL/HQL query, you are on your own. In some cases (I'm not telling that it is Your case), Criteria might generate better, more optimized queries.

I have always used this rule:

- If the query is simple enough - use JPQL
- If it is complicated - use Criteria
- If it is too complicated for Criteria - thing about Stored Procedure or redesign

Comment: Its the same strategy I apply. Except for the 3rd. I will try to stay away from SP. If database is handed over to you, there is only so much you can redesign. What strategy would you go for if you had to use DetachedCritera? I wrote this with HQL.

Comment: Why do you need DetachedCriteria? Do you need to prepare your query outside of Transaction/Session context?